# How to Parse This Json Using Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json

I have the following json:

```
{
  "2003": [
    null,
    "L1qyqggJ32FLmM",
    "https://www.ecstasycoffee.com/37-awesome-silver-and-white-christmas-tree-decorating-ideas-inspirations/",
    "37+ Awesome Silver And White Christmas Tree Decorating Ideas ...",
    null,
    null,
    null,
    "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSFBSzxWz5xAj2cd8lJPr0MZzrhA-rFJQ8IolK9Y6ewe2_2Y9ZL",
    null,
    false,
    null,
    null,
    "EcstasyCoffee"
  ]
}
```

I'm having a problem accessing "2003" section, how do I read that value?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code!

Comment: looks like `Dictionary<string, object[]>` ...

Comment: you can map "2003" to JsonProperty attribute

Comment: "i have problem accessing the field that contain url" What problem?

Answer (score 3):

Use a `Dictionary<string, object[]>` as type:

```
var r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object[]>>(json);
```

You can access the `2013` node like this:

```
object[] valuesOf2013 = r["2013"];
```